# PayPal Access and Permissions API..?

Tags: paypal

I'm a little bit confused about the use of PayPal Access.  I know that I can use it to allow users to create an account or log into my site/application, but will that alone allow me to make API calls on their behalf, too, or do I still need the Permissions API?

For example, I'm going to build a simple app that allows users to void or capture against orders/authorizations.  I'd like to use PayPal Access to allow users to sign up for this app very easily, but then do I have to send them through the PayPal login flow again with the Permissions API, or how does that work?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is something that is not available at this time.  You would have to send the buyer through the Permissions API flow.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused.  I've got PayPal Access working already to sign in to an app.  Just not sure what to do at that point.  Are you saying I would hve to go ahead and send them through thte PayPal login twice?

Comment: Correct, you would have to then send them back through the PayPal login, to grant permissions to your API to be used on their account.